# Stanford NLP ported to ikvm, FileLoad Exception

Tags: exception, stanford-nlp, ikvm

I'm trying to use the Stanford NLP tools ported to IKVM, but it gives me unhandeled exception.

here's the code I'm using

```
       `string StanfordModelsDirectory = "englishPCFG.ser.gz";
        try
        {
            LexicalizedParser LP = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(StanfordModelsDirectory);

            TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
            GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();


            Tree parse = LP.apply("what's the largest city in canada?");
            parse.pennPrint();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }`
```

I've referenced IKVM.OpenJDK.Core and stanford-parser, but the message 
"Could not load file or assembly 'IKVM.OpenJDK.Core, Version=7.1.4532.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)" appears.

I'm using windows 8 (visual studio 2012, .NET 4.5)

Comment: This error is a standard error of .NET version hell and has nothing to do with IKVM or NLP. Do you have compiled the stanford-parser with the same version of IKVM?

Comment: I didn't compile the Stanford-parser, I got the dll compiled. but I got the java files for the parser, how can I get a .MET assembly from them. and which files I'll use. thanks :)

Comment: If you use an existing .NET dll then you need all dependencies in the right version. I think the dll was compiled with a different IKVM version. If you want compile it self then you can look at et [wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Convert_a_jar_file_to_a_dll_and_use_it_as_library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IKVM is compiled for .NET 2.0. You need to add a config file to your application to map to a different .NET version like 4.5.

IKVM 7.2.x contains such config file for ikvm.exe, ikvmc.exe, .....

Comment: the config file contains         <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" /> so I think it's for .NET 4.5

Comment: I compiled the jar files myself and it works, thanks a lot. you can edit your answer as I marked it as an answer :)